# Screen Overlay detected

Tags: android, android-animation, android-alertdialog, android-permissions

I have `MyFragment` inside `MyActivity`. `MyFragment` contains a `Dialog` that is used as a permissions explainer. I used `Animator` to animate the `AlertDialog`.

No where in the code am I calling a Toast or Snackbar or anything else. So I am sure that there's no toast interacting with android's permissions view.

```
public void showPermissionExplainer() {
        final View dialogView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_permission_explainer_view, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        final AlertDialog permissionExplainer = builder.create();
        permissionExplainer.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    revealShow(dialogView, true, null, false);
                else
                    permissionExplainer.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnNo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    revealShow(dialogView, false, permissionExplainer, false);
                else
                    permissionExplainer.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnContinue).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    revealShow(dialogView, false, permissionExplainer, true);
                else
                    permissionExplainer.dismiss();
            }
        });
        if (permissionExplainer.getWindow() != null)
            permissionExplainer.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        permissionExplainer.show();
    }
```

`revealShow()` is where I animate the dialog and contains the `onAnimationEnd` method.

Next I thought that animation might be an issue since the dialog gets dismissed later on. And so, I asked for permission after the animation was complete and view hidden and

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        dialog.dismiss();
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(askForPermission) {
             final Handler handler = new Handler();
             handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       Log.d(TAG, "run: Running after 1 sec");
                                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_SMS);
                   }
             }, 1000);
       }
}
```

Unfortunately, this also did not solve the issue. I then tried delaying asking permissions which solved the problem, but only if I put a delay of at least 2-3 seconds. With a delay of 1 sec, I still get the issue.

My question is, how do I find out exactly what's causing this behaviour? 
Also, is this behaviour normal for a Dialog inside a fragment?